# Copy .txt files in a certain directory in linux

Tags: linux

I already created the directories but my problem is when I get to the copying the txt file in the Directory. I need help

> Demonstrate your grasp of the Unix file system by constructing a
>   directory structure as follows:
>
> In your home ( ~ ) directory, create a directory named “UnixCourse”.
>
> This directory will be used in the remaining assignments of this
>   course, as well as this one.
>
> Several of the commands that you will issue in this course will
>   examine files in this directory and, in some cases, send me a listing
>   of those files or even copies of those files for grading and
>   diagnostic purposes. So you should not store anything unrelated to the
>   course assignments in this ~/UnixCourse area.
>
> Within your UnixCourse directory, you should create a directory named
>   “fileAsst”. Within that directory, you should create two directories,
>   named “Empire” and “Alliance”.
>
> Use the ls command to check your work.
>
> Within the Empire directory, you should place a copy of the file
>   ~cs252/Assignments/fileAsst/darth.txt
>
> Use the ls command to check your work.
>
> Within the Alliance directory, you should place a copy of the file
>   ~cs252/Assignments/fileAsst/r2d2.txt
>
> Use the ls command to check your work.
>
> When you have completed this much, execute the command
>
> ~cs252/bin/fileAsst-1
>
> (Take note of the difference between the numeric digit 1 and the
>   lower-case letter l in the command above. If you can’t tell the
>   difference between these, check your web browser settings to see if
>   you can get it to use some better fonts.)
>
> This will check to see if you have built the desired directory
>   structure so far. You should repeat the above steps as necessary until
>   this command reports success.
>
> If you have been successful so far, the fileAsst-1 command will have
>   placed a new file somewhere in the directory structure you have built.
>   Find it, and move it into the Empire directory, renaming the file to
>   “emperor.dat”.
>
> Execute the command
>
> ~cs252/bin/fileAsst-2
>
> If all is well, you will receive the access code for completion of
>   this assignment.

This is what I've tried:

```
Last login: Wed Sep 4 12:18:33 2019 from 128.82.4.29
slahjiri@sirius:~$ cd UnixCourse
slahjiri@sirius:~/UnixCourse$ cd fileAsst
slahjiri@sirius:~/UnixCourse/fileAsst$ cd Empire
slahjiri@sirius:~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Empire$ ls NewFile.txt NewFile.txt.
slahjiri@sirius:~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Empire$ ~cs252/Assignments/fileAsst/darth.txt
-bash: /home/cs252/Assignments/fileAsst/darth.txt: Permission denied
slahjiri@sirius:~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Empire$
```

Comment: It's a difficulty. If we tell you the answer straight up then because it's trivial for your teacher to identify you - in the same way that it's trivial for us to identify your educational institution - your copying an answer here may be classed as plagiarism. You probably need to look up your notes on the `cp` command.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: When you just type `~cs252/Assignments/fileAsst/darth.txt`, bash tries to run it instead of copying it. `~cs252` means the home directory of the `cs252` user, which you may not have access to?